# SequelizeJS - insert JSONB to Postgres with raw query - how to escape

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I want to insert a row with JSONB content as a raw query. The problem is that I get error wherever I insert any "nontrivial" JSON object.

These are examples of my raw SQL queries:

Error for all of these: SequelizeBaseError: invalid input syntax for type json

```
'INSERT INTO "sometable" ("id", "createdAt", "updatedAt", "custom_data") VALUES (DEFAULT, NOW(), NOW(), \'"{something:\"value\"}"\')';
'INSERT INTO "sometable" ("id", "createdAt", "updatedAt", "custom_data") VALUES (DEFAULT, NOW(), NOW(), \'"{\"aaa\":\"ss15\"}"\')';
```

This last one works, but only with integer values:

```
'INSERT INTO "sometable" ("id", "createdAt", "updatedAt", "custom_data") VALUES (DEFAULT, NOW(), NOW(), \'"{a:10}"\')';
```

I've tried so many possible combinations of escaping the JSON-like string, even inserting real JS object, and nothing worked.

Answer (score 11):

Try to `JSON.stringify()` first:

```
var customData = JSON.stringify({"name":"George Washington","presidentNo":1});
```

Comment: Confirmed on Sequelize V6 as well